# Не переведено уведомление о совершённой правке во время редактирования сообщения новичка (из очереди проверок)

Tags: дефект, локализация

В оранжевом блоке, «This post has been edited...».

[This post edited http://pokit.org/get/img/9970414f5cda9558703b0273eb538586.jpg](http://pokit.org/get/img/9970414f5cda9558703b0273eb538586.jpg)

**UPD**: блок всплывает не только при редактировании сообщений новичков из очереди проверок. Вчера, когда D-side [опередил меня](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/130243/revisions) с редактированием вопроса, он тоже появился.

Comment: не нашёл ничего похожего на это сообщение в *transifex*-е. вероятно, следует сообщить об этом в «upstream».

Comment: Пожалуйста, напишите всю строку целиком. К сожалению, на изображении не разобрать, что написано.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, «This post has been edited 1 time since you began. Your edit can only be saved if it is more thorough than the currently saved edit.» А [**так**](http://pokit.org/get/img/9970414f5cda9558703b0273eb538586.jpg) видно? Для удобного просмотра подобного рода картинок предназначены [моё](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2910/199934) и [не только](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2830/199934) предложения, которые, к сожалению, заминусили. Спасибо.

Comment: @alexolut, «возможный дубликат» появился в августе 2016, моя тема — в апреле. Спасибо.

Comment: Хронология не важна, важно наличие ответов и красные метки.